# Ionic - View Doesn't refresh when relaunched from the side menu

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

From my Side Menu, I have a view that loads two calls for action - scan barcode or search product when initially loaded.  Once I a make a selection, the rest of the view is dynamically populated.  Once it is dynamically populated and if I go back to the Side Menu to reload the view so that I can only see my original calls for action, I cannot see that.  Instead I still see the dynamically populated state.  At the beginning of the controller I have the following calls. $ionicNavBarDelegate.showBackButton(false), $ionicHistory.clearHistory(), $ionicHistory.clearCache().

I tried initializing the view with an empty function so that it causes the scope to reset however that didn't not help.  Is there a way to trigger a fresh session every time I launch from the side menu?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by creating an empty controller that will redirect me to myview. The refresh worked magically every time.